# better way to create tables in hive from CSV files using pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a `6` `CSV` files in `HDFS`. `3` are present in directory called `/user/data/` and `3` in `/user/docs/`.

`/user/data/` has `tab_team, tab_players, tab_country` CSV files.

`/user/docs/` has `tab_team, tab_players, tab_country` CSV files.

Even though the the names are same these files have different data in them.

Now using these CSV files I want to create tables in Hive using `pyspark`

I have done like below.

```
file_list = ['tab_team', 'tab_players', 'tab_country']

for team in file_list:
    df = sqlContext.read.load("/user/data/{}/*.csv".format(team), format='com.databricks.spark.csv', header='true', inferSchema='true')

    df.registerTempTable("my_temp_table")

    sqlContext.sql("create table {}.`data_{}` stored as ORC as select * from my_temp_table".format(db_name, team))


for team in file_list:
    df = sqlContext.read.load("/user/docs/{}/*.csv".format(team), format='com.databricks.spark.csv', header='true', inferSchema='true')

    df.registerTempTable("my_temp_table")

    sqlContext.sql("create table {}.`docs_{}` stored as ORC as select * from my_temp_table".format(db_name, team))
```

I got what I want. But as you see here most of the code is duplicate code. I would like to reduce the duplicity of the code. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about another loop?

```
file_list = ['tab_team', 'tab_players', 'tab_country']
file_path = ['data', 'docs']

for team in file_list:
    for path in file_path:
        df = sqlContext.read.load("/user/{}/{}/*.csv".format(path, team), format='com.databricks.spark.csv', header='true', inferSchema='true')

        df.registerTempTable("my_temp_table")

        sqlContext.sql("create table {}.`{}_{}` stored as ORC as select * from my_temp_table".format(db_name, path, team))
```